# InputMismatchException with scanner.nextInt() over socket

Tags: java

server

```
 import java.net.ServerSocket;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class ServerLNS extends Thread {

 final static int porta=8888;



public static void main(String[] args) 
{


    try 
    {

       new ServerLNS().startServer(); //start server

    } 

    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Problema con Input/Output " + ex.getMessage());//
    }
}

public void startServer() throws Exception 
{
    Scanner sc;

    ServerSocket serverSocket=null;
    Socket socket = null;
    boolean ascoltando=true;
    boolean b=true;
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(porta);//avvia il server con il  numero di porta
     // ******  interfaccia f=new interfaccia);

        while(ascoltando)
        {

            socket = serverSocket.accept();

           new handlerClient(socket).start();//metodo ereditato dai thread che fa partire run e gestisce il client sul socket
            //socket è la connessione virtuale tra un computer e un altro (INDIRIZZO)

        }

    //serverSocket.close();


} 

 }
```

handle

```
   package server;

   import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.BufferedWriter;
   import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
     import java.net.ServerSocket;
     import java.net.Socket;
 import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;


 public  class handlerClient extends Thread
 {

Socket _socket;
String name = "";
String ok="OK";
Scanner sc;
public handlerClient(Socket socket) throws IOException
{
_socket=socket; 
}
@Override
public void run()  //parte ill thread quando viene eseguito {(.start) in ServerLNS}

{
    try //parte ill thread quando viene eseguito {(.start) in ServerLNS}
    {
        sc=new Scanner(_socket.getInputStream());
        FileOutputStream fout;
        BufferedInputStream bis=null;
        BufferedReader br1=null;
        br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_socket.getInputStream()));
        bis=new BufferedInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());
        String filename;
        String nome_cartella;
        filename=br1.readLine();
        nome_cartella=br1.readLine();

        System.out.println(filename);
        fout=new FileOutputStream(nome_cartella+"/"+filename);



        int size=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("file created");
        int ch=bis.read();
        System.out.println(ch);
        System.out.println("after bis.read()");

        while(size>0)
        {
            fout.write(ch);
            System.out.println(ch);
            ch=bis.read();
            size--;
        }

        System.out.println(ch);
        System.out.println("data written");
        PrintWriter pw1=new PrintWriter(_socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        pw1.println("DATA UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        sc.nextInt();
        Logger.getLogger(handlerClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        }
}
```

client

```
    package clientprova;

    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
  import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
     import java.io.PrintWriter;
   import java.net.InetAddress;
     import java.net.Socket;


  public class ClientProva {
   final static int porta=8888;//porta server dove si collegano i client

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,   IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here

int i;
BufferedInputStream bis;
BufferedOutputStream bos;
PrintWriter pw;
BufferedReader br;
File file = new File("Selezione_012.png");


 InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
 Socket sock = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 8888);

bis=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        bos=new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        pw=new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(),true);
        br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        pw.println(file.getName());
        pw.println("prova");

    int ch=bis.read();
    int counter=0;
    pw.println(file.length());

    while(counter<file.length())
    {
        bos.write(ch);
        System.out.println(ch);
        ch=bis.read();
        counter++;
    }

    System.out.println(ch);
    bos.write(ch);
    bos.flush();
   // pw.flush();
     }


}
```

sorry for the too much code i have a problem with this line in HANDLE, with error inputMismatchException, but but this does not happen when I use the client with a basic server without the multiclient - thread management, to test I called boolean b = sc.hasNextInt before sc.nextInt int size = ( ) if multiclient gives me false , I do not understand the problem. Thanks in advance

```
       fout=new FileOutputStream(nome_cartella+"/"+filename);



        int size=sc.nextInt();<-----------------------------------
        System.out.println("file created");
```

this server working, is the same of the first server but in this Server Socket is not given as a parameter to the thread , this may affect ?

```
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.util.Scanner;


     public class ServerProva {

final static int porta=8888;//porta server dove si collegano i client

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket serverSocket=null;

    boolean ascoltando=true;
    boolean b=true;
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(porta);//avvia il server con il  numero di porta
    Socket s;
    BufferedReader br1=null;
     // ******  interfaccia f=new interfaccia);
        String filename;
        String nome_cartella;
      boolean r=true;
      BufferedInputStream bis=null;
       Scanner sc;
    FileOutputStream fout;

    while(ascoltando)
        {

        s=serverSocket.accept();<--------------// this socket 


     br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
     bis=new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        filename=br1.readLine();
        nome_cartella=br1.readLine();

            System.out.println(filename);
            fout=new FileOutputStream(nome_cartella+"/"+filename);
            sc=new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(sc);

            int size=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("file created");
            int ch=bis.read();
            System.out.println(ch);
            System.out.println("after bis.read()");

            while(size>0)
            {
                fout.write(ch);
                System.out.println(ch);
                ch=bis.read();
                size--;
            }

            System.out.println(ch);
            System.out.println("data written");
            PrintWriter pw1=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
            pw1.println("DATA UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY");
        }

    serverSocket.close();
}
```

}

Comment: That formatting... it hurts.

Comment: @bcsb1001 sorry for this, I wrote everything in a hurry

Comment: HI, even if you're busy, if my answer's useful, may you take a minute to select my answer as accepted one? This will help a little bug in StackOverflow be more willing to participate here =) Thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File.length()` returns `long`, so you should do `long size = sc.nextLong()` instead.